# Exercise 5.2, Atiyah-MacDonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $A\subseteq B$ be two rings, with $B$ integral over $A$. Given an algebraically closed field $k$, show that any homomorphism $f:A\to k$ extends to a homomorphism $g:B\to k$.

Let $p:=\operatorname{ker} f$. It is a prime ideal being $k$ an integral domain, and being $A\subseteq B$ integral there is a prime ideal $q\subset B$ whose contraction is $p$ (theorem 5.10). So we can reduce to the case that $A,B$ are integral domains and $f$ is injective. Under these assumptions, $f$ extends to an injection $f':\operatorname{Frac}A \to k$. Now *if $\operatorname{Frac}A\subseteq \operatorname{Frac}B$ was an algebraic extension*, we would have $\operatorname{Frac}B\subseteq k$ (because $k=\bar k$), and $g$ would be $B\to \operatorname{Frac}B\to k$ (keep in mind that we assumed $A,B$ integral domains). However I fear that the sentence in *italics* is false. I couldn't prove it with mere calculations, and I only saw that $\operatorname{Frac}A\subseteq (A^\times)^{-1}B$ is integral, that is quite trivial. How should I proceed?

Comment: The elements of $B$ are algebraic over Frac$(A)$, because they are even integral over $A$. Since, the algebraic elements from a field, it follows that all elements of Frac$(B)$ are algebraic over Frac$(A)$.